# create pdf in addition to word docx using officer

Tags: r, reporters, officer

I am using officer (used to use reporters) within a loop to create 150 unique documents. I need these documents however to be exported from R as word docx AND pdfs.

Is there a way to export the document created with officer to a pdf?

Answer (score 9):

That's possible but the solution I have depends on libreoffice. Here is the code I am using. Hope it will help. I've hard-coded libreoffice path then you probably will have to adapt or improve the code for variable `cmd_`.

The code is transforming a PPTX or DOCX file to PDF.

```
library(pdftools)
office_shot <- function( file, wd = getwd() ){
  cmd_ <- sprintf(
    "/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir %s %s",
    wd, file )
  system(cmd_)

  pdf_file <- gsub("\\.(docx|pptx)$", ".pdf", basename(file))
  pdf_file
}
office_shot(file = "your_presentation.pptx")
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with using system() and am having trouble figuring out how to get it to make the pdf and export that without then going on to making a png. Every time I run office_shot() I am getting the error message:  Error in normalizePath(pdf, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="/Users/amanda/Documents/reports/ACAD_2014.pdf": No such file or directory     But of course not because they are .docx files in the folder that I need to convert to pdfs

Comment: Hi David, do you have an idea how to use this on windows?

Comment: I don't work on windows but I am pretty sure that by changing the path of soffice to a valid path it should work.

Comment: Quick response :-), thanks, I've found it, had to add .exe and quote " " the path

Comment: Hi Arcoutte, I tested under Windows by replacing to `sprintf(" 'D:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice.exe' --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir %s %s", wd, file) system(cmd_)`, but it's not working out. Did I make mistakes in the path?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using RDCOMClient to convert my OfficeR created docx's to PDFs.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

file <- "C:/path/to your/doc.docx"
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application") #creates COM object
wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(Filename=file) #opens your docx in wordApp
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs("C:/path/to your/doc.pdf"), FileFormat=17) #saves as PDF 
wordApp$Quit() #quits the COM Word application
```

I found the FileFormat=17 bit here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat

I've been able to put the above in a loop to convert multiple docx's to PDFs quickly, too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not available for R 3.6 for those using it.

Comment: True, and since I wrote this I have abandoned RDCOMClient. I use {reticulate} to access Python's {win32com.client} and from there do basically the exact same thing. It's pretty cumbersome if you don't already have R/{reticulate}/Python already, but it works in just the same way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to convert your `docx` into the `pdf`. There is a function `convert_to_pdf` from the [`docxtractr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docxtractr/index.html) package.

Note that this function is using LibreOffice to convert `docx` to `pdf`. So you have to install LibreOffice before and write the path to the `soffice.exe`. Read more about paths for different OS [here](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/docxtractr/issues/5#issuecomment-233181976).

Here is a simple example how to convert several `docx` documents into `pdf` on the Windows machine. I have Windows 10 and LibreOffice 6.4 installed. Just imagine that you have `X` Word documents stored in the `data` folder and you want to create the same amount of PDF in the `data/pdf` folder (you have to create the pdf folder before).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(docxtractr)

# You have to show the way to the LibreOffice before
set_libreoffice_path("C:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice.exe")

# 1) List of word documents
words <- list.files("data/",
                    pattern = "?.docx",
                    full.names = T)

# 2) Custom function
word2pdf <- function(path){
  
  # Let's extract the name of the file
  name <- str_remove(path, "data/") %>% 
    str_remove(".docx")
  
  convert_to_pdf(path,
                 pdf_file = paste0("data/pdf/",
                                   name,
                                   ".pdf"))
  
}

# 3) Convert
words %>%
  map(~word2pdf(.x))
```

Comment: This solution works, thanks for sharing.